# Alaxos Acl plugin internationalization issue

Tags: cakephp, acl, cakephp-2.6

Im using alaxos Acl plugin for managing user roles and groups in my cakephp 2.6 project,the plugin use english as the default language, the problem i want to change it to the french language in my cakephp project, but i don't know how.
i added 
`Configure::write('Config.language', 'fre');`  to the bootstrap.php of the plugin or the bootstrap.php of my main application but it didn't work.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just made me realize that I always see my own plugin in English as well...

The point is that at some point ([Internationalizing Your Application](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html#internationalizing-your-application)) the french code has changed from `fre` to `fra` but I've never updated the plugin.

Rename the folder `plugins/Acl/Locale/fre` to `plugins/Acl/Locale/fra`, and use `Configure::write('Config.language', 'fr')` and it should work.